# Example fail fast circuit breaker with Spring Cloud / Reactive

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I am looking at the [Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker](https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/16/introducing-spring-cloud-circuit-breaker) example with respect to using a Reactive API. I understand the basics and how the fallback mechanism works for `WebClient` but can't see how to implement a fail-fast solution for when the circuit breaker is open.

This would be the example method I would like to make 'fail-fast' (taken from the article).

```
public Mono<String> slow() {
        return webClient.get().uri("/slow").retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class).transform(it -> {
            CircuitBreaker cb = cbFactory.create("slow");
            return cb.run(it, throwable -> 
                            Mono.just("fallback"));
                });
    }
```

Any help or insight into this much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There's not a separate handler for circuit open, just the fallback.

Comment: That is sort of my point.  The code example in the documentation shows the fallback mechanism but does not discuss how circuit open/close is implemented and acts.

Comment: The fallback is called if the circuit is open.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase this.  Normally the circuit breaker wraps an operation that may fail.so it can handle fail fast on entry and failures to fallback.  An example would be using  @HystrixCommand in Spring which wraps the operation in a proxy. What I'm not seeing in the reactive examples is the operation to fail fast before an attempt is made to execute the operation. Ignore the fallback as this isn't the the part I'm trying to understand.

Comment: If the circuit is open, the operation is not tried. The circuit breaker just wraps hystrix or resilience 4j. They don't operate any differently